# Synchronize Gmail but not contacts

Tags: sync, gmail

I have a phone with Android 4.2.2.

I want to sync my mails but not my contacts.

The problem is that it seems to be joined in my phone.

When I go to `Settings > Account > Google` I can activate synchronisation but not choose which one.

Does anyone knows how to do this or an app that allows this?

Answer (score 3):

When you tap Google in your accounts list, the first option shows your user mail. Tap that and you will see a list of services which are getting synced. Untick Contacts and make sure Gmail is checked.

[image: screen shot]